# symfony cascaded dropdown list

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am using Synfony3. I have 3 entities called "category, "services", "Profile" and the relation between is C <1-n> S <1-n> P. In other term, 1 category can have multiple services, 1 service can have multiple profiles.

When I display the form to hydrate a profile I would to have 1 dropdown with all services and 1 dropdown list with all categories

To do so, I have put in ProfileType the services dropdownlist as following

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType {
       //...
       ->add('service',        EntityType::class, array(
            'class'        => 'xxxBundle:Service',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple'     => false,
        ))
```

How can I add the category then as there is no direct connection between Category and Profile

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the response to Alsatian and Dbrumann, I build some examples with short explanation [here](https://github.com/DavidTra/symfony3_form_with_cascaded_droplist)

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the examples provided to be able to deal with entities (put the listener in a separated service and inject the EntityManger to load the choices ...) :

**How to cascade select fields**

This is an example to show how to change the allowed choices on a subCategory select field depending on the value of the category select field.
To do that you have to make your subCategory choices dynamical for both client and server side.

1. Make the form dynamic on the client side for display
   Example of client side dynamic form (using Javascript / JQuery) :

   ```
   $('#category').change(function(){
       switch($(this).val()){
           case '1': // If category == '1'
               var choice = {
                   'choice1_1':'1_1',
                   'choice1_2':'1_2',
                   'choice1_3':'1_3',
               };
           break;
           case '2': // If category == '2'
               var choice = {
                   'choice2_1':'2_1',
                   'choice2_2':'2_2',
                   'choice2_3':'2_3',
               };
           break;
           case '3': // If category == '3'
               var choice = {
                   'choice3_1':'3_1',
                   'choice3_2':'3_2',
                   'choice3_3':'3_3',
               };        
           break;
       }

       var $subCategorySelect = $('#subCategory');

       $subCategorySelect.empty();
       $.each(choice, function(key, value) {
           $subCategorySelect.append($('<option></option>')).attr('value',value).text(key);
       });
   });
   ```

   Of course you could get the choices from an AJAX call. That's not the purpose of this example.
2. Make the form dynamic on the server side for initialisation and validation
   Example of server side dynamic form :

   ```
   namespace AppBundle\Form;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;

   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
   use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;

   class MyBaseFormType extends AbstractType
   {
       /**
        * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
        * @param array $options
        */
       public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
       {
           $builder
               ->add('category',ChoiceType::class,array('choices'=>array(
                       'choice1'=>'1',
                       'choice2'=>'2',
                       'choice3'=>'3',
                   )))
           ;

           $addSubCategoryListener = function(FormEvent $event){
               $form = $event->getForm();
               $data = $event->getData();

               switch($data['category']){
                   case '1': // If category == '1'
                       $choices = array(
                           'choice1_1'=>'1_1',
                           'choice1_2'=>'1_2',
                           'choice1_3'=>'1_3',
                       );
                   break;
                   case '2': // If category == '2'
                       $choices = array(
                           'choice2_1'=>'2_1',
                           'choice2_2'=>'2_2',
                           'choice2_3'=>'2_3',
                       );                        
                   break;
                   case '3': // If category == '3'
                       $choices = array(
                           'choice3_1'=>'3_1',
                           'choice3_2'=>'3_2',
                           'choice3_3'=>'3_3',
                       );                        
                   break;
               }

               $form->add('subCategory',ChoiceType::class,array('choices'=>$choices));
           };

           // This listener will adapt the form with the data passed to the form during construction :
           $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, $addSubCategoryListener);

           // This listener will adapt the form with the submitted data :
           $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, $addSubCategoryListener);
       }
   }
   ```